# Error of Control+ calibration test on CAT D11

Tags: technic, software, control-plus

I've just finished building set [42131](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42131-1) Cat D11 Bulldozer, but unfortunately I couldn't do the final calibration before driving it...

I carried out the tests during construction and everything was OK.

Now, at the first stage of calibration, the shovel goes up and down correctly and then nothing, the application freezes without going on to the next stage...

Thanks in advance for your answers!